# Custom Formatting Dates in Excel

Tags: excel, format

I was wondering if there if anyway to custom format dates on excel

For example if I have a date in the form of 20171214, how can I format this to 14-Dec-2017?

Comment: very important question, do the day and month have leading zeros? ie what would january 1st, 2017 look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=--REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,7,0,"/"),5,0,"/")
```

then format: `dd-mmm-yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

Say:

```
=1*(LEFT(A1,4)&"/"&MID(A1,5,2)&"/"&RIGHT(A1,2))
```

then apply a Format of choice.